# How to write IF and AND functions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft

I am trying to write a formula that will return with a "1" or "0" under the "Expected Workdays" column (AH) if:

- Start Date>=Period and Term Date>=Period, return 1
- Start Date>=Period and Term Date="", return 1
- Start Date<Period and Term Date="", return 0
- Start Date>=Period and Term Date<=Period, return 0
- Start Date<Period and Term Date<Period, return 0

[image]

Been playing with the functions but I can't seem to get the desired result. Appreciate much your help, everyone!

I tried =IF(AND(AI2>=A2,OR(AJ2>=A2,AJ2="")),1,0) but it's throwing back the opposite result. Should I switch to 0,1?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJmTH.png)

Comment: what if they are both < Period?

Comment: still return a 0 in that case..thanks for catching that.

Comment: Welcome to SU. As a best practice, please don't answer questions or add info in comments, rather [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1770393/edit) your question as I now did for you. This way your question is up-to-date with your situation, it can get more focused, and the relevant info is readily available for the community.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and the tip. will remember that, going forward. :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that we can test if start date is greater then period and term date is either greater than period or blank to return `1` all other cases lead to `0`

```
=IF(AND(Start Date>=Period,OR(Term Date>=Period,Term Date="")),1,0)
```

Comment: Hi Scott, I tried =IF(AND(AI2>=A2,OR(AJ2>=A2,AJ2="")),1,0) but it's throwing back the opposite result. Should I switch to 0,1?

Comment: Those match what you stated in the question.  If the start data IS GREATER OR EQUAL to Period and Term Date IS GREATER OR EQUAL to Period or Term Date is "" it should be 1.  Are you sure you did not mean `<=` Where Period would be a date AFTER Start and Term Dates? @Widdy  Remember that the larger the date the later in time it happened. As in '2023-01-30' is less than '2023-02-01'

Comment: My bad - I think, this is what I meant: "<= Where Period would be a date AFTER Start and Term Dates?"

Comment: Then play with the `>=` and see if you can get what you want by changing one at a time to `<=`

Comment: Looks like I finally got it: =IF(AND(AI2<=A2,OR(AJ2>=A2,AJ2="")),1,0). Appreciate much your help, Scott!